# Are There any Cases When ReadProcessMemory Would Fail?

Tags: windows, winapi, error-handling, process, readprocessmemory

I am currently writing a program that utilizes `ReadProcessMemory` to save a block of memory to a file as text. Within the program, the user will designate the base address and size of the memory block. Input validations are done before the call to `ReadProcessMemory` to ensure that there are no parameter-related errors. Memory bounds are also restricted to pre-allocated regions to ensure that the user does not attempt to read non-allocated memory. Due to the fact that all allocated memory is readable, I believe that there should not be a need to perform general post-call error checking for `ReadProcessMemory`. Am I correct in stating this? Assuming all parameters are valid, of course. I have used `ReadProcessMemory` many times before in the past with proper error checking and found it to be unnecessary because the function always succeeded.

Examples would also be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, there are, as is clearly stated in the [ReadProcessMemory documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory). It also tells you how to find out why it failed using `GetLastError()`. And you *always, always, always* check the return values of API calls. Without exception. Failing to do so just sets you up for failure and difficult to trace bugs.

Comment: Memory regions can be marked executable but not readable. Memory can be secured, too. Just because memory is allocated doesn't imply that *you* can read it. Plus, you cannot check for allocated memory without introducing a TICTTOU race. Besides, it's unclear what *practical* programming problem you are trying to solve by using an API outside its specification.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that all parameters are valid:

- The `handle` have `PROCESS_VM_READ` access to the process;
- `lpBaseAddress` is valid;
- `nSize` <= the size of `lpBuffer`.
- ...

I think the only factor that will cause `ReadProcessMemory` failure is [Memory Protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/memory-protection-constants) attributes.

As @IInspectable: "memory is allocated doesn't imply that you can read it".

After testing, I found that the following situations will get failed.

- `PAGE_NOACCESS`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/reserving-and-committing-memory

```
lpvBase = VirtualAlloc(
                 NULL,                 // System selects address
                 PAGELIMIT*dwPageSize, // Size of allocation
                 MEM_RESERVE,          // Allocate reserved pages
                 PAGE_NOACCESS);       // Protection = no access
```

- `PAGE_GUARD | ...`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/creating-guard-pages

```
lpvAddr = VirtualAlloc(NULL, dwPageSize,
                 MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT,
                 PAGE_READONLY | PAGE_GUARD);
```

Or modified by [`VirtualProtectEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualprotectex):

```
VirtualProtectEx(hProcess, lpAddress, dwSize, PAGE_NOACCESS, &old);
```

and

```
VirtualProtectEx(hProcess, lpAddress, dwSize, PAGE_GUARD | PAGE_READONLY, &old);
```

`GetLastError` will return 299(`ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY`)

Use [`VirtualQueryEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualqueryex) to retrieve the The access protection of the pages in the specified region